# highcharts group points with same date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcahrts dataGrouping, in our case we have points with exactly same date, but for some reason highcharts not grouping them, it is grouping only points with time differences.
this is our configuration:

```
dataGrouping : {
                        enabled : true
                        approximation : 'average',
                        groupPixelWidth : 115, // how close the points can be before grouping happens
                        smoothed : false, // if true, grouped points will stick to the edge of the xAxis which
                        // looks weird
                        units : [
                            [
                                'second', [
                                    0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30
                                ]
                            ], [
                                'minute', [
                                    0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30
                                ]
                            ], [
                                'hour', [
                                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12
                                ]
                            ], [
                                'day', [
                                    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
                                ]
                            ], [
                                'week', [
                                    1
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        dateTimeLabelFormats : getDateFormats(),
                    }
            }
```

Comment: after investigating the issue, I understood that the issue is with approximation : 'average'. I provide to it 2 points: 1 with the time 9:51:30 and the second 9:52:31. the average time that highcharts calculate is 9:00. What I am missing here? the average time is not correct and hide my grouped points because it is out of chart range.

Comment: Can you make a live example of the issue? Average grouping seems to work fine - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/tb3ovhak/

Comment: Hi here you can see example with grouped points: jsfiddle.net/shahard/6jesdckc/29  each point represents group, in the tooltip you can see first point, last point and the average that highcharts calculate. you can see this is not correct.

Comment: Approximation works on y values of the group - so the average is taken not from the x values, datetimes, but y values - this.x in the formatter won't the average. Also, I think that what you try to achieve here does not fit the grouping feature - you need to process the data before you render the chart.

Comment: I don't understand, so how the grouping working at all in our case? 
all our y values are the same (value = 1), and still we see that the grouping is working with x values.you still can see that highcharts changing  the value of grouped point to unknown value.

Comment: Grouping splits the available space in chunks and gathers points which belong to the same chunk - then there are grouped points and based on them it is created one grouped point with y value = by default average of grouped points y values (approximation option). The value this.x (you refer it as the average) is not the average. It has different algorithm based on groupPixelWidth, number of points, space and smoothed option, so the x of the grouped point can exceed the range of the grouped points x values - as in your example.